# Uniform convergence of a function fn(x)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

The task is: Does the function 
$$
f_n(x)= \frac{2nx}{(1+n^2x^2)} 
$$

convergence uniformly in the interval [0,1]? And in (1, +infinity)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried? What are your thoughts on your question?

Comment: do you know the supremum definiton of uniform convergence

Comment: Idea: you could calculate the minimum and maximum values of the function (as a function of $n$)

Comment: The definition of $f_n$ tells us that it should make sense to check the points $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and see what happens there.

Comment: When x=1/n fn(x) = 2?

Comment: Thank you so much!